# cfsavecontent + cfinclude with utf-8 charset?

Tags: coldfusion, character-encoding

I have a line of coldfusion code that includes an cfm file encoded with the utf-8 charset and saves it to a variable.  The problem I am having is that there is no way to specify a charset in cfinclude and the resulting variable does not seem to be reading utf-8 correctly so any non ascii characters are rendered incorrectly.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="content">
  <cfinclude template="test.cfm">
</cfsavecontent>
<cfoutput>#content#</cfoutput>
```

If I use cffile this is not a problem because I can specify a chaset, but the file is not parsed for coldfusion variables.

```
<cfset path = expandPath(".") & "\test.html">
<cffile action="read" file="#path#" variable="content" charset="utf-8">
<cfoutput>#content#</cfoutput>
```

So my question - **Is there a way to load a parsed coldfusion file into a variable while honoring a specific charset**?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if this will work or not, but the only thing I can think of is to put a

```
<cfprocessingdirective pageencoding="utf-8" />
```

tag at the very top of the code being included (test.cfm).  This instructs CF to use a specific encoding when compiling the code.

Comment: This does work and I greatly appreciate the answer.  I would prefer not to alter the included files but if this is not possible this will be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the cfprocessingdirective in both the included file and the master file.